# How would a bank run instance be handled by a DEX?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, economics, cryptoeconomics

How would a DEX like Uniswap handle a hyptothetical situation where every LP in a pool tries to withdraw at the same time?

At any instance, taking into consideration the trading activities in a liquidity pool, the amount that is owed to LPs will be lesser than the amount that can be withdrawn. I understand that dynamic asset pricing based on supply and demand may incentivise traders against depleting the total supply and increasing the gap between owed and staked amount. But does anyone have any detailed idea about the economics of a bank run situation?

Comment: There is no bank run, as you say "he amount that is owed to LPs will be lesser than the amount that can be withdrawn".
Found this about stablecoins which might interest you https://sabretoothsg.medium.com/uniswap-is-the-reason-why-algo-stablecoins-cant-maintain-the-peg-and-how-to-fix-it-91e9f7f93d4f